# telnet connection failed on port 23

Tags: cmd, telnet

i'm suppose to log into remote machines using telnet but in the task i have, there's no ip adresses for that ! instead i have hostnames. i'm a bit new in this and i don't know what i'm suppose to get. i'm asked to try these following:

```
>telnet cs.purdue.edu
>telnet crete.dcs.gla.uk
```

i keep getting the same result:

```
Connecting To .......Could not open connection to the host, on 
port 23: Connect failed
```

i know the telnet command usually requires two arguments but it's not specified in this task! i tried to enable telnet on services but i didn't find it,  i also restarted the pc after downloading the telnet client and even tried to run the command several times and in two different computers but still the same result ! is there any solutions or clarification for this problem ?

OS : win 10

Comment: Without any reference to programming this question is off topic here and should better be asked on [su].

Comment: thank you i found some questions of this topic soo i thought i can ask it in here !! thank you again

Comment: If you want an IP address for a DNS name, use `nslookup cs.purdue.edu`.